# In Mongo, how do you get all of something that appears only in other objects?

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

According to [a tutorial I'm reading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_data_modeling.htm), a MongoDB for a blogging system should have a central collection for `Posts` which contains details about the posts, and a sub object containing all the comments in the post.

```
{
   _id: POST_ID
   title: TITLE_OF_POST, 
   description: POST_DESCRIPTION,
   by: POST_BY,
   url: URL_OF_POST,
   tags: [TAG1, TAG2, TAG3],
   likes: TOTAL_LIKES, 
   comments: [  
      {
         user:'987',
         message: TEXT,
         dateCreated: DATE_TIME,
         like: LIKES 
      },
      {
         user:'123',
         message: TEXT,
         dateCreated: DATE_TIME,
         like: LIKES
      }
   ]
}
```

What I don't understand however is why is this efficient? For instance, what if I wanted to get all of a specific users comments? Wouldn't that take a long time or a lot of processing power to go through all the posts to see if the user posted there?

Comment: 1. What you have to do for that is process your data through mongo mapreduce jobs / aggregators and keep the processed data ready as per your requirement is one way i can think of.  2. Also if your sub objects have an "_id" then keep the ids in a lookup table in a different place so that you could just call it when required is another way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think how you will work with this data. It for sure is not be perfect model for Alall scenarios, however if u think how it will work in blog application it makes sense. Users usually display blog post with All the comments, this way you can retriever data in one go. If you need to to query for specific comments, this model is not the best.

Comment: Sometimes I'd like a user to be able to see all the comments he/she posted. It seems inefficient to go through thousands of posts to look if this made comments there (perhaps he only commented on a handful)

Comment: So it seems that you should use different model and separate these two. Blogs are more read intensive than write so u should adjist to that. The best way IMO is to think in terms of screens in your APP and data you will need to populate them

Comment: It can't be that MongoDB is so incapable. I've seen systems that use it that are capable of doing these sorts of things really fast. There must be a simple way or everyone would just use RDBs

Comment: if the only requirement regarding the comments you have is to get the comments for specific user then this can be easily done (and quite fast) to extract the comments from "post" document by creating and index on "comments.user" and then using aggregation framework. If most of the time you will display posts and only from time to time display comments of specific user than it will work.